# JSON:PP only encodes first item in array

Tags: json, perl, perl-module

I'm pushing my values into the array...

```
while ( ... ) {
  push @array, { label => "label", value => "value" };
}
```

This appears to be working.

Then...

```
use JSON::PP ;
print JSON::PP->new->utf8->encode(@array) ;
```

only generates...

```
{"value":"value","label":"label"}
```

but I need...

```
[{"value":"value","label":"label"}{"value":"value","label":"label"} etc.. ]
```

(each item in array outputted, not just the first one...)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try passing a reference to the array:

```
print JSON::PP->new->utf8->encode(\@array) ;
```

Encode is documented to take a scalar, not an array (so you need the reference, which is a scalar).